# c++ vector<char> erase() error, won't compile

Tags: c++, vector, char, erase

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void makeVector();
void breakVector();

vector<char> asciiChar;
vector<char> shuffledChar;

int main(){
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
    makeVector();
    breakVector();
}

void makeVector(){
    for(char i = 32; i < 127; i++){
        asciiChar.push_back(i);
        cout << i << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}

void breakVector(){
    for(int i = 0; i < asciiChar.size(); i++){
        int j = rand() % asciiChar.size();
        shuffledChar.push_back(asciiChar.at(j));
        asciiChar[j].erase();                   //34 error *******
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 95; i++){
        cout << shuffledChar.at(i) << "  ";
    }
}
```

.

```
...|31|warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]|
C:\Users\Owner\Documents\C++\asciiShuffle\main.cpp|34|error: request for member 'erase' in 'asciiChar.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<char, std::allocator<char> >(((std::vector<char>::size_type)j))', which is of non-class type '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char> >::value_type {aka char}'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I am trying to delete the location in the vector that was used to assign a value to my other vector to avoid duplicate values.  This code should be creating a vector and shuffling it's contents into another.

I have used .erase() in a similar function in another program and it worked for me but I don't understand this error message and my search results are turning up unrelated.

Comment: `char`s don't have members, `erase()` or otherwise.

Comment: So can I not delete a char type vector element?

Comment: Not like this. do it via iterators and call `erase()` on the vector itself (as in @Isuka's answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
asciiChar[j].erase();
```

You are trying to use the erase() method on a char element, and not on the vector itself.

[erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) is a method of the vector class. So you have to use it on your `asciiChar` vector and not on an element of the vector.

Also do note that you should **never** erase an element from a vector while you are iterating on its elements.

What you want to achieve is probably this:

```
while(asciiChar.size() > 0){
    int j = rand() % asciiChar.size();
    shuffledChar.push_back(asciiChar.at(j));
    asciiChar.erase(asciiChar.begin() + j);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I still don't know very much.